# Rummikub buying two jokers

Tags: rummikub

Can I buy Two joker's and use them with two cubes from my hand?  For example. 3 j j 6.
Or is it necessary to have two cubes for each joker?

Comment: Unfortunately like many other rummikub joker rules questions, this is unanswerable without a copy of the rules you are playing to. I've played two different editions of rummikub, and the rules they had on jokers were *wildly* different. In one edition, I would agree with [Toon Krijthe's answer](https://boardgames.stackexchange.com/a/42495/11743), in the other there were no restrictions on joker use at all.

Answer (score 1):

From [these rules](http://www.boardgamecapital.com/game_rules/rummikub.pdf):

> A joker that has been replaced must be used in the player's same turn with 2 or more tiles from his rack to make a new set.

So if you have retrieved a joker from another set, you must place it with tiles from your rack (this can also be a joker). Which could be interpreted as place the retrieved joker in a set using only tiles from your hand.

I know it does not explicitly says you can not use tiles from the table, but the "with 2 or more tiles from his rack to make a new set" is clear enough for me.

Of course, you can always add house rules. Or the rummikub set/edition you have may have different rules.

Comment: Edit proposed. See [this comment](https://boardgames.stackexchange.com/questions/41697/rummikub-buying-two-jokers/42495#comment58625_41697) for a fuller explanation.